# How to use Group by for tables in relation?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, ado.net

I have two tables called PatientMaster and DoctorsMaster. The relationship between them is Many to one. Now I'm trying to write a simple condition something like this and I guess I'm writing the LINQ wrong.

```
partial void PrintDocLetter1_CanExecute(ref bool result)
{
  if (this.PatientsMasterItem.DoctorsMasterItem
                             .GroupBy(i => i.DoctorsName)
                             .Any(l => l.Count() > 1))
  {
    result = false;
  }
}
```

How can I put a condition like if different patients have same doctor then do this ? The bigger picture is I can send letter 1 only if the doctor has one patient and letter 2 if doctor has more than 1 patients where Letter 1 is sent to one of the patients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood your question do you want something like this

```
var Doctor = PatientsMasterItem.DoctorsMasterItem;

var PatientList = Doctor.PatientMasterItems;

if(PatientList.Count() > 1)
{

}
else
{

}
```